# Dynamic v-model problem on nuxt application

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a dynamic v-model input. All seems well except for the following.

The on click event that triggers the checkAnswers method only works if you click out of the input then click back into the input and then press the button again. It should trigger when the button is pressed the first time.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
<template>
  <div class="addition container">
    <article class="tile is-child box">
      <div class="questions">
        <ul v-for="n in 5">
          <li>
            <p>{{ randomNumberA[n] }} + {{ randomNumberB[n] }} = </p>
            <input class="input" type="text" maxlength="8" v-model.number="userAnswer[n]">
            <p>{{ outcome[n] }}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button @click="checkAnswers" class="button">Submit Answer</button>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        randomNumberA: [] = Array.from({length: 40}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)),
        randomNumberB: [] = Array.from({length: 40}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)),
        userAnswer: [],
        outcome: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      checkAnswers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          if (this.userAnswer[i] === (this.randomNumberA[i] + this.randomNumberB[i])) {
            this.outcome[i] = 'Correct';
          } else {
            this.outcome[i] = 'Incorrect';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some basic issues with your use of the template syntax here. According to the vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions):

> One restriction is that each binding can only contain one single
> expression, so the following will NOT work:  {{ var a = 1 }}

If you want to populate your arrays with random numbers you would be better calling a function on page mount. Something like this:

```
mounted() {
  this.fillArrays()
},
methods: {
  fillArrays() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.randomNumberA.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
      this.randomNumberB.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
      this.answer.push(this.randomNumberA[i] + this.randomNumberB[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use template syntax to display your arrays.

It looks like you are setting up a challenge for the user to compare answers so I think you'd be better to have a function called on input: Something like:

```
<input type="whatever" v-model="givenAnswer[n-1]"> <button @click="processAnswer(givenAnswer[n-1])>Submit</button>
```

Then have a function to compare answers.

**Edit**

I have basically rewritten your whole page. Basically you should be using `array.push()` to insert elements into an array. If you look at this you'll see the randomNumber and answer arrays are populated on page mount, the userAnswer array as it is entered and then the outcome on button click.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div >
      <ul v-for="n in 5">
        <li>
          <p>{{ randomNumberA[n-1] }} + {{ randomNumberB[n-1] }} = </p>
          <input class="input" type="text" maxlength="8" v-model.number="userAnswer[n-1]">
          <p>{{ outcome[n-1] }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button @click="checkAnswers" class="button">Submit Answers</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      randomNumberA: [],
      randomNumberB: [],
      answer: [],
      userAnswer: [],
      outcome: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fillArrays()
  },
  methods: {
    checkAnswers() {
      this.outcome.length = 0
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (this.userAnswer[i] === this.answer[i]) {
          this.outcome.push('Correct');
        } else {
          this.outcome.push('Incorrect');
        }
      }
    },
    fillArrays() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this.randomNumberA.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
        this.randomNumberB.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
        this.answer.push(this.randomNumberA[i] + this.randomNumberB[i])
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it's very much appreciated! I tried your answer and unfortunately couldn't get it to show the randomNumber arrays via the for loop. It seemed that the v-for renders before the array is injected via the mounted function but I couldn't get to the bottom of it. I used the workaround (edited my original post) instead but am now stuck with something else. Everything works as expected but the on click event that triggers the checkAnswers method only works if you click out of the input then click back into the input and then press the button?!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the fillArrays method I had didn't work. I've edited it now. You're much better doing it like this than having functions in your data function, they will usually cause problems.

Comment: Perfect! Works great. Thanks for the help it was incredibly insightful.

Comment: No problem. If you are happy with the answer please mark it as correct.

Comment: Have done but it doesn't show because my reputation is less than 15 unfortunately.